# glGenBuffers fails to create one despite GL_NO_ERROR

Tags: opengl-es, vertex-buffer

I have a curious case where `glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo )` leaves vbo set to zero, and yet `glGetError()` returns **GL_NO_ERROR**

This has been observed (though rare) on a customer Android device: Xiaomi/Redmi 6A

If `glGenBuffers()` generates an object name 0, surely it should have reported a failure via `glGetError()` I assume?

Or is this the device's way of telling me it is out of GPU memory?

Comment: Zero is a valid buffer id, right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: From the spec: The name zero is reserved by the GL; for some object types, zero names a default object of that type, and in others zero will never correspond to an actual instance of that object type.

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug to me ...

Comment: I agree with solidpixel, this sounds like a driver bug. Please consider reporting the issue to the driver developer on their [forum here](https://forums.imgtec.com/) with further details. They may be able to provide a work around.